# string index out of range, appears in random lines

Tags: python

I tried to make a small program that generates text like this:

```
M E T A  
E E  
T   T  
A     A
```

My code:

```
line = 0
word = raw_input("")

for i in word:
  print i,

print

for i in range(len(word)):
  line += 1
  print word[line] + " " * (line*2-1) + word[line]
```

It seems to technically work, but results in

> *Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python", line 11, in  IndexError: string index out of range*

which can appear in different lines depending on input length. Also, if I input nothing, it will act as if I input RUN instead, but only sometimes. What's the reason behind this weird behaviour? I'm running it within Codeacademy's python lesson, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Use your `i` variable: `print word[i] + " " * (i*2-1) + word[i]`, the last value of `line` is `len(word)`

Answer (score 0):

If you already iterating over word chars your `line` var is useless. It will be enough to do just this:

```
for i in range(len(word)):
   print word[i] + " " * (i*2-1) + word[i]
```

Or even something like this:

```
for i, ch in enumerate(word[1:]):
  print ch + " " * ((i+1)*2-1) + ch
```

`enumerate` here is built-in function to iterate over some collection(word is collection here) and enumerate(index) each element. So on each iteration `emumerate` returns index of the element `i` and element itself `ch`.
`word[1:]` is operator for taking subset elements from the collection. It means that we will take all values begining from value with index `1`.

Comment: Enumerate would work if the first line was not an special case where you have to write every letter. Either you use conditionals inside or you use a `range(1, len(word))` and just `print(" ".join(word))` before the loop

Answer (score 0):

String indexes go from `0` to `len(string)-1`. Your variable `line` has value `len(word)` in the last iteration, so the expression becomes `word[len(word)]`, which overshoots the index by 1 and results in an "IndexError: string index out of range".

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed that now. But could you explain why the IndexError appears in different lines depending on my input length? With a short word it always appears at the end, but when it exceeds a certain length the error pops up in random lines. Why is that? Shouldn't it always appear at the last iteration?

Comment: Please post your modified code, the actual error message (stack trace) and let us know which version of Python you're using, and I'll be glad to have a look.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. After modification to `for i in range(len(word)-1):` it works perfectly, I was simply asking about how the error messages appeared in the old code. Anyways, it seems like it was all due to Codeacademy's buggy IDE, it doesn't seem to happen elsewhere. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The logical doesn't work either, you need the following:

```
word = raw_input("Insert a word: ").upper()

print(" ".join(word))
for i in range(1, len(word)):
    print(word[i] + " " * (i*2-1) + word[i])
```